# How do I push from Travis to AWS bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, travis-ci

I have aws bucket set up in the Oregon region.  I also have a domain tied to this bucket so I do not have to enter in the long aws path.  I would like to push builds from travis to the s3 bucket.  But i get this error

**The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint**

Now I did some research and it seems if the bucket was US Region instead then I would be able to use the domain bucket name.  I tried to use the long path to access the site but that also doesnt seem to work anymore.  I get an xml file instead.

If there way around this so I do not have to recreate the bucket in US Region?  And if that does resolve the issue, why?  Why do the buckets behave differently?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please give a link of  or add your `.travis.yml` to this? It makes it a lot easier for us to see what you are doing. :)

Comment: https://github.com/skinnybrit51/booty-grid/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: https://travis-ci.org/skinnybrit51/booty-grid/builds/22148100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set the region of the s3 endpoint easily: Here is your build tweaked to set a s3 region and endpoint:

```
deploy:
    provider: s3
    edge: true
    bucket: "skinnybrit51.com"
    endpoint: "s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
    region: "us-west-2"
    upload-dir: "booty-grid"
    skip_cleanup: true
    secret_access_key:
        secure: zDiuEZgn1THVJyvqE4FcKXPXY/Aozy2gm1gHDkHCooVoZuRtU31tz1N6zWp3yVJ3JZFk4zDO7zyWGjtAba5ydh8FNOl+F/L0RVpYfiSpoiJA7PZlXAw1WKPiyY21luCctZeJc/eZry8ZseM190Q+UzbiqLLjtteO1CHeZo3XptM=
    access_key_id:
        secure: yj/T/lSSr1MMyUZMiS2IGqvFG78ExJQi06wxa5+7M2Rfz1G5LaiVH+9mqcE5qVmu1q54/CmwT1OUNdeXy/SUOwre4L7ZshS9LfK/7BcATMjIvCSysNT3AEOIx63NtRWabzQMiQu25h5owVbvwTBMN6N6+C/g5yq46XQsvoy6xz8=
    local-dir: public
    on:
        branch: master
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Where did you find the additional tag information out?  It is not stated anywhere on S3 deployment page.  http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/s3/ .  Also, why do you have to add this additional property information in when the region is not US Standard.  Thanks

Comment: I'm the person who programmed the s3 uploader. :) There's no documentation because this is a new feature that hasn't be released yet. `edge: true` downloads the beta version of s3 uploader. I'll write up about this soon.

Comment: You have to add endpoint because s3 websites have to be accessed from a different endpoint than the normal s3 one. S3 can normally find the region the bucket is in automatically, but with a custom endpoint from the s3 website, no autodetection is performed, so you  have to explicitly set the region.

Comment: Is it possible to drop S3 cache after deployment?